# Is slow charging bad for the battery?

Tags: battery, battery-life, charging

I know that charging the battery too fast can overheat the battery and shorten battery life. But is charging it slowly, e.g. from a USB 2.0 cable plugged to a laptop, also harmful for the battery? I know there is a 'USB charging mode' designed for this, but I am not so sure if it is bad for the battery.

I have Googled, but most links are forums where people offer their opinions and personal experiences, I want to know whether someone has actually tested this out?

Answer (score 4):

Slow charging is great for a lithium battery. Two things kills lithium batteries

1. Temperature
2. Charge level

   - Charging too fast causes excess heat, that damages lithium batteries
   - Keeping your battery charge too high also damages lithium batteries

Ideally you want to slowly recharge and keep it between 20% - 80%. Also, many short small charge cycles is better than a lengthy large charge cycle.

Sources: http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_prolong_lithium_based_batteries

Comment: Welcome to [android.se]. While you disclosed your product, I removed the product promotion since it's not asked on the question, and we try to encourage neutral answer. You can instead put some info about your product on your "About me" section on your profile.